# PHP uniqid() no longer unique after updating PHP to 5.3.26

Tags: php, unique, zend-server

Anyone else discover that PHP is no longer producing unique values for `uniqid()` after updating to 5.3.26? My previous version was 5.3.16.

It's not a minor problem. My DOM IDs are generated with that function for all jQuery UI Buttons, and a lot of them have duplicate IDs.

I've changed the code from `uniqid("button")` to `uniqid("button",true)` but it didn't change the results. Still getting duplicate IDs.

This happen after updating Zend Server free edition to the latest build.

Is there a solution to this? Refactoring the code to use integer counters is not a small task, and means I have to retest everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I was able to fix my problem by doing the following.

Change:

```
 $id = uniqid('button');
```

To

```
 $id = str_replace('.','-',uniqid('button',true));
```

That includes an extra number appended with a dot. Which creates invalid DOM IDs (in my case) so I just replace it with a dash.

Answer (score 0):

uniqid() only provides a **probability** of unicity. If you really want a unique ID you'll have to use an incremented integer.

That said there's a really small chance of having duplicate uniqids. Are you truncating the result of uniqid() in any way ?

Comment: No, but looking at the IDs it seems like the score of uniqid is no longer milliseconds. So successively quick calls to uniqid produces duplicates. I'll append a counter value and that'll fix it for now, but I'll have to stop use uniqid.